# How can I write a function in VBA to extract cell references from a formula?

Tags: excel, regex, vba

I currently have a function which can extract the cell reference using vbscript.regexp which is not something I am particularly familiar with, however for the most part it works. The idea is to populate a list with each of the references from a formula, containing the workbook name (if an external workbook), sheet name (if a different sheet to the one where the input cell is) and finally the cell being referenced.

For example, if my input cell has a formula of simply "=AA111" then my function when applied to this cell will output "AA111" (which I can then use to determine the page number of where this cell is. In a more complicated example, if my input cell has a formula of "=[WorkbookName]SheetNameA!AB222 + SheetNameB!AC333" then my function would return "[WorkbookName]SheetNameA!AB222" and "SheetNameB!AC333". I am then able to 'read' these strings by looking at the positions of the ']' symbol which denotes the end of the workbook reference (if any) or the '!' which denotes the end of the sheet reference (if any).

The code I am currently using is as follows;

```
Public Function CellRef(CellInput As Range) As String

CellRefDetector = "'?([a-zA-Z0-9\s\[\]\.])*'?!?\$?[A-Z]+\$?[0-9]+(:\$?[A-Z]+\$?[0-9]+)?"

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
.Global = True
.MultiLine = True
.IgnoreCase = False
.Pattern = CellRefDetector
Set Results = .Execute(CellInput.Formula)
End With
```

I am using the regex string as developed here: https://www.get-digital-help.com/extract-cell-references-from-a-formula/

This works perfectly with the following issue; there are some characters (particularly operators) which I would like to be found and included within a workbook name or sheet name, but that I would like to not be found such that I can separate sums of different cells as different references. These include; + - _ / \ all of which may be found in the name of a workbook or sheet but I would also want to split up the reference in between different references.

For example, in my above code, a '+' operator in the workbook name will cause the workbook name to only be taken past that point. For example, "=[WorkbookName+Example]SheetNameC!AD222" would return "Example]Sheet_name_C!AD444" However, if I include a '+' operator in the regex line (i.e. included within my search of the regex), then the function will include something like "=AA111+AB222+AC333" all as one cell reference and not distinguish between them.

I hope I have given enough information for someone to provide assistance! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide, **as text** which can be copied, a selection of various references and exactly what you want extracted from each one. Include the one's with which you are having trouble. Suggest using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to make it easy to copy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is any use to you, but a teacher friend of mine asked me for some code that would do more or less the same thing as you are asking.

The trick to those `Workbook` and `Worksheet` names which contain operator characters is that they'll always be bound by an inverted comma. So we can temporarily remove those items before identifying genuine operators.

There'll doubtless be an easier and quicker way to do it, but in the shortness of time, this is what I came up with for my friend:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function RangesInFormula(target As Range) As Variant
    Dim str As String
    Dim item As Variant, items As Variant
    Dim addr As String, result As String
    
    'Sense checking
    If target.Cells.Count <> 1 Then
        RangesInFormula = CVErr(xlErrRef)
        Exit Function
    End If
    If Not target.HasFormula Then Exit Function
    
    'Split formula into array.
    items = SplitFormulaByOperators(target)
    
    'Try to grab an address from each formula item.
    For Each item In items
        If Len(CStr(item)) > 0 Then
            addr = RangeToString(CStr(item))
            If Len(addr) > 0 Then
                If Len(result) > 0 Then result = result & "|"
                result = result & addr
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    'Return the addresses if there are any.
    If Len(result) > 0 Then
        RangesInFormula = result
    End If
End Function

Private Function RemoveTextBetween(startChar As String, endChar As String, sourceText As String) As String
    Dim startPt As Long, endPt As Long
    Dim tmp As String
    
    tmp = sourceText
    Do While True
        endPt = InStr(tmp, endChar)
        If startChar = endChar Then
            endPt = InStr(endPt + 1, tmp, endChar)
        End If
        If endPt = 0 Then Exit Do
        startPt = InStrRev(tmp, startChar, endPt - 1)
        If startPt = 0 Then Exit Do
        tmp = Left(tmp, startPt - 1) & Right(tmp, Len(tmp) - endPt)
    Loop
    
    RemoveTextBetween = tmp
End Function

Private Function SplitFormulaByOperators(target As Range) As Variant
    Const OPERATORS = "+|-|*|/|%|^|>=|<=|<>|=|>|<|&|(|)"
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim opr As Variant, ex As Variant
    Dim tmp As String
    Dim extractedList As Collection
    Dim extracted(1) As String
    Dim oprs() As String, result() As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    'Convert constant to array.
    oprs = Split(OPERATORS, "|")
    
    'Remove text between quotes
    tmp = target.formula
    tmp = RemoveTextBetween("""", """", tmp)
    
    'Temporarily extract workbook and sheet names which have operators in them.
    'They can be identified by bounding inverted commas.
    Set extractedList = New Collection
    Do While True
        extracted(0) = ExtractTextBetween("'", "'", tmp, excludeMarkers:=False)
        If Len(extracted(0)) = 0 Then Exit Do
        extracted(1) = "|ex" & extractedList.Count & "|"
        ex = Empty: On Error Resume Next
        ex = extractedList(extracted(0)): On Error GoTo 0
        If IsEmpty(ex) Then
            extractedList.Add extracted, extracted(0)
            tmp = Replace(tmp, extracted(0), extracted(1))
        End If
    Loop
    
    'Replace the operators
    For Each opr In oprs
        tmp = Replace(tmp, opr, "|op|")
    Next
    
    result = Split(tmp, "|op|")
    
    'Trim whitespace and commas.
    For i = LBound(result) To UBound(result)
        result(i) = TrimWhitespace(result(i), &H2C)
        'Convert back to the extracted values.
        For Each ex In extractedList
            result(i) = Replace(result(i), ex(1), ex(0))
        Next
    Next
    
    'Return the array.
    SplitFormulaByOperators = result
    
End Function

Private Function ExtractTextBetween( _
    startChar As String, _
    endChar As String, _
    sourceText As String, _
    Optional acceptStartOfStringToEndChar As Boolean = False, _
    Optional acceptStartCharToEndOfString As Boolean = False, _
    Optional excludeMarkers As Boolean = True) As String
    
    Dim i As Long, startPt As Long, endPt As Long
    Dim tmp As String
    
    For i = 1 To Len(sourceText)
        tmp = Mid(sourceText, i, Len(startChar))
        If startPt = 0 Then
            If tmp = startChar Then
                startPt = i
            End If
        Else
            If tmp = endChar Then
                endPt = i + Len(endChar) - 1
                If excludeMarkers Then
                    startPt = startPt + Len(startChar)
                    endPt = endPt - Len(endChar)
                End If
                tmp = Mid(sourceText, startPt, endPt - startPt + 1)
                ExtractTextBetween = tmp
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If startPt > 0 And endPt = 0 And acceptStartCharToEndOfString Then
        If excludeMarkers Then
            startPt = startPt + Len(startChar)
        End If
        tmp = Right(sourceText, Len(sourceText) - startPt + 1)
        ExtractTextBetween = tmp
        Exit Function
    End If
    If endPt > 0 And startPt = 0 And acceptStartOfStringToEndChar Then
        If excludeMarkers Then
            endPt = endPt - Len(endChar)
        End If
        tmp = Left(sourceText, endPt)
        ExtractTextBetween = tmp
        Exit Function
    End If
    
End Function

Private Function RangeToString(addr As String) As String
    Dim rng As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Evaluate(addr)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    'We have a range, so the address can be returned as valid reference.
    RangeToString = addr
        
End Function
Private Function TrimWhitespace(txt As String, ParamArray additionals() As Variant) As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, c As Long
    Dim startPos As Long, endPos As Long
    Dim whitespaces As Variant
    Dim isWhitespace As Boolean
    
    ' List of whitespace characters.
    whitespaces = Array( _
        &H9, &HA, &HB, &HC, &HD, &H20, &H85, &HA0, _
        &H1680, &H2000, &H2001, &H2002, &H2003, &H2004, &H2005, &H2006, _
        &H2007, &H2008, &H2009, &H200A, &H2028, &H2029, &H202F, &H205F, _
        &H3000, &H180E, &H200B, &H200C, &H200D, &H2060, &HFEFF)
    
    ' Find the first non-whitespace.
    For i = 1 To Len(txt)
        c = Asc(Mid(txt, i, 1))
        isWhitespace = False
        For j = LBound(whitespaces) To UBound(whitespaces)
            If c = whitespaces(j) Then
               isWhitespace = True
               Exit For
            End If
        Next
        For j = LBound(additionals) To UBound(additionals)
            If c = additionals(j) Then
               isWhitespace = True
               Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not isWhitespace Then
            startPos = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    ' If there's no start position, return an empty string.
    If startPos = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    ' Find the last non-whitespace.
    For i = Len(txt) To startPos Step -1
        c = Asc(Mid(txt, i, 1))
        isWhitespace = False
        For j = LBound(whitespaces) To UBound(whitespaces)
            If c = whitespaces(j) Then
               isWhitespace = True
               Exit For
            End If
        Next
        For j = LBound(additionals) To UBound(additionals)
            If c = additionals(j) Then
               isWhitespace = True
               Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not isWhitespace Then
            endPos = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    TrimWhitespace = Mid(txt, startPos, endPos - startPos + 1)
End Function
```